# Fluent C# Builder

Tags: c#, fluent

Wanted to write some fluent like this...

```
new Actor().DoSomething<Type>().WithOption(options).When(Conditions);
```

I understand method chaining and how to pass action to subsequent method / object.

For example, action of DoSomething will be passed to object containing WithOption method and action of withOption passed to the object containing When method.

It could be something like

```
interface Actor {
  ActorOption DoSomething<T>();
}

interface ActorOption {
  ActorCondition WithOption();
}

interface ActorCondition{
  void When();
}
```

So actual action happens in WHen method. All are fine so far.

To execute the code with default option or no condition, it could be called as `new Actor.DoSomething<T>().WithDefaultOption().Always();`

My worry is what if someone leaves the code in middle, which means `new Actor.DoSomething<T>()`. It appears the actor is supposed to do something, which is fluently right.

I am not able to think of design which can cover similar scenario. Please suggest.

PS: I am writing wrapper over some third party class, so I do not have full control on internal implementation. For example, I cannot set condition once options are set or vice versa.

Comment: do you want a builder? or just a fluent interface?

Comment: I need pattern to implement such class.

Comment: You can have a builder...  Or a fluent interface... Or both. It doesn't look like you are making a builder with your example code but it's a different answer depending on what you want

Answer (score 1):

if you write

```
new Actor().DoSomething<Type>().WithOption(options).When(Conditions);
```

You could write alternative:

```
Actor actor = new Actor();
doResult = actor.DoSomething<Type>();
optionResult = doResult.WithOption(options);
conditionResult = optionResult.When(Conditions);
```

So you can see that your options and your condition added after you execute DoSomething, so it have no effect for the method DoSomething. If you execute your code finally in the When method, it is not intuitive. Better you prepare your actor and get your result with executing DoSomething() ("lamda-style").

And if someone leave some method calls.. Yeah of course then its missing... If it is necessary, you have to add it as a parameter in DoSomething. If not, you have to define default options, which are used if no options specified.

Comment: hungryMind mentions using several interfaces, not a single class, so this doesn't really apply. He's using the type system to enforce method calls (e.g. you can only call `WithOption` on the result of `DoSomething`, not on an `Actor`).

Comment: Sorry, its late ;) Changed my answer a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

The actual action shouldn't happen in the `When` method. Instead, try making your fluent interface so that the last method "does something":

```
new Actor<Type>().WithOption(options).When(Conditions).DoSomething();
```

So your actor will be configured first and then run. If you don't like this syntax, you can still go for something like:

```
new Actor().DoSomething(config => config.WithOption(options).When(conditions));
```

Comment: This is an alternate way and looks logical. However, my question was to identify some design if I want it that way.

Answer (score -1):

there are several method of monad Maybe, they should help you.

```
public static class Maybe
{
    public static TResult With<TInput, TResult>
        (this TInput o, Func<TInput, TResult> evaluator)
        where TInput : class where TResult : class
    {
        return o == null ? null : evaluetor(o);
    }

    public static TResult Return<TInput, TResult>
        (this TInput o, Func<TInput, TResult> evaluator, TResult failureValue)
        where TInput : class
    {
        return o == null ? failureValue : evaluator(o);
    }

    public static bool ReturnSuccess<TInput>(this TInput o)
        where TInput : class
    {
        return o != null;
    }

    public static TInput If<TInput>(this TInput o, Predicate<TInput> evaluator)
        where TInput : class
    {
        if (o == null)
            return null;
        return evaluator(o) ? o : null;
    }

    public static TInput Do<TInput>(this TInput o, Action<TInput> action)
        where TInput : class
    {
        if (o == null) return null;
        action(o);
        return o;
    }
    public static TInput If<TInput>(this TInput o, Func<TInput, bool> evaluator)
        where TInput : class
    {
        if (o == null) return null;
        return evaluator(o) ? o : null;
    }        
}
```

Comment: I can't see how this helps, or is even related to the question.